# How to remove custom module provided entity instances by the time the module being uninstalled?

Tags: 8, entities, installation

I have the following use case:

1. I have a custom module, which defines a custom entity type.
2. The custom entity type has some content in the database.
3. Module needs to be uninstalled now, but it can't, since "There is content for the entity type" (which is true, there is content)
4. How to extend the uninstall process of the module to first remove all the content instances and then do the rest?

I tried `hook_uninstall`, but that didn't help. Any ideas?
Content can't be uninstalled by hand! (bigger project issue)

Answer (score 2):

A potential [duplicate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194185/truncate-tables-before-uninstalling-a-module-in-drupal-8).

The short answer (as I can see), you **CAN'T** **right now** remove content by the time you uninstalling the module. That makes you (us) to do it in two steps:

1. Write a `update_hook` where you remove all the content of the custom entity
2. You uninstall the module. 
   (drush cex, which removes the module from
       core.extension.yml)

Comment: Indeed a duplicate of that, but since then, https://www.drupal.org/node/2688945 came a long way and is almost finished, which will make this possible.