# How can I uninstall a module with entities in the db?

Tags: 8, entities, installation

How can I uninstall a Drupal 8 module with entities in the db?

I have made a dev module that implement content entities created using the drupal console. I've added fields, views, and made some modifications.
But, when I try to uninstall the module, there is a error:

```
The following reasons prevent the modules from being uninstalled:
There is content for the entity type: xxx
```

Where xxx is the entity type name. If I delete the entities manually or via code, I can disable the module. But I wanted a easier way, allowing the module to delete the entities itself. I tried using **hook_uninstall()**, but apparently it is called after the triggering error.

I did't found the answer googling. Maybe my wording was wrong...

Anyaway. Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some sort of a shortcut, but it might not be what you are looking for.

If you go the *Uninstall tab* of the *Extend page*, for all modules that define content entities you'll see:

[image: delete]

The Remove content items link will delete all entities in a batch operation, after which you can uninstall the module. So you don't have to remove them one-by-one or from the database, but it requires some extra mouse clicks...

UPDATE

There is also [`hook_module_preuninstall($module)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!module.api.php/function/hook_module_preuninstall/8.2.x), which might be of help for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is thrown on the line `if ($reasons = $this->validateUninstall($module_list)) {`, which is before the `$this->moduleHandler->invokeAll('module_preuninstall', array($module));`. (and before the hook_uninstall too).

Comment: Ah too bad. I was somewhat expecting that would work. I suppose you will have to do it with my first idea then...

Comment: I've found another question asking the same thing, and its a known bug for now... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194185/truncate-tables-before-uninstalling-a-module-in-drupal-8?rq=1